# Transparent text inside opaque box

Tags: css, transparency

I want to have transparent text in the following situation for the menu item in this dropdown that is highlighted.  In the example below, what i want to achieve is that the leg would be the visible color in the 'QUIR', and the grass be visible in the 'EMENTS'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could make the Background of the 'Tech Requirements' Text to be transparent.

Comment: Please provide more details on how to do this, otherwise this is not an answer, just a comment.

Comment: i wish to retain the white background of tech requirements.